# Why am I getting an "Empty Response" when changing source files in setasign?

Tags: php, fpdi

I'm using setasign V1 as our servers are yet to be updated past 5.5.9 and am trying to import the first page from 3 different pdf's to create a new pdf.  But if I use any more than one file, I get an error.

I am also running this using the Slim framework and have had to add namespaces to each of the setasign files to get them to read in.

It works perfectly with single files, but not when trying to get a page out of multiple files.

In my below code, the loop goes through each file to get the first page and then add some text.  This is a function where I pass in an array of "jobs" and also the $savedFile path to save to.

If I put the line "$pdf->setSourceFile($file)" before the loop  and define $file as any of the files in the $inputFiles array, it works fine but obviously has just the first page of the first file on each of the 3 pages created.  It also works if I make it bring in just the second file or just the third.  But if I put this line inside the loop I get an Empty Response error.
I have also tried to unset the parser at the end of each loop but that didn't make any difference.

At the moment, I can't figure out where it's going wrong as no error details are thrown.

```
$pdf = new FPDI();
$inputFolder = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/' . $app->config->get('saveLocations.COC') . '/';      
$inputFiles = [];
foreach($jobs as $job){
    $coc = $app->coc_approval->getCOC($app, $job);
    $cocFile = $coc->file;      
    array_push($inputFiles, $inputFolder . $cocFile);   
}

foreach($inputFiles as $file){
    $pdf->setSourceFile($file);
    $pdf->AddPage();

    $tpl = $pdf->importPage(1);
    $pdf->useTemplate($tpl, 0, 0, null, null);
    // Set font and color
    $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica');
    $pdf->SetFontSize('10');
    $pdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0); // RGB
    // Add Customer and PO details
    $x = 75.5;
    $pdf->SetXY($x,67);
    $pdf->Cell(0, 15, $customer);
    $pdf->SetXY($x, 73);
    $pdf->Cell(0, 15, $PO); 
    //unset($pdf->parsers[$file]);
}           
$pdf->Output($savedFile, 'F');
```

I am expecting the first page of each file listed in the $inputFiles array to be saved in the final output pdf.

Any advice would be very much appreciated thanks!

Comment: You save the result to the local path which is in `$savedFile`. FPDF itself doesn't have an error as `empty response`. So you should check why the saved file is not forwarded to the response object, or?

Comment: Hi Jan, the issue seems to be with changing the source file.  If I change the code to use just one file by defining another variable $onefile outside of the loop and then call $pdf->setSourceFile($onefile) inside the loop, then it works fine and saves a 3 page file with the same page repeated.  But if I put a new file link inside the ->setSourceFile method it fails with no response.  I'm thinking I might need to remove the original set file first?

Comment: In your code you never ever initiate a response. The code looks ok. Did you checked the content of the resulting file $savedFile? Do you reach this line at all? How do you handle errors?

Comment: Hi Jan, the content of the $savedFile is fine as long as I don't change the source file in the process, if I do, then it fails at this line and never gets to the output line. I'm thinking that it may be trying to re-create a class as I get that error if I try and create a file for each individual file input.  I'll look further into that. Errors are being caught by an overriding Slim framework method, but if I try and put a specific catch around this line, then it also given an empty response error.

Comment: If you never reach the `Output()` call there is an exception thrown before. You just have to have your error reporting under your control to get a meaningful error message.